# How to determine the correct buffer size for SQLBindCol

Tags: c, odbc, buffer, unixodbc

The `SQLBindCol` function expects a buffer length (for certain buffer types, like strings):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710118(v=vs.85).aspx

```
SQLRETURN SQLBindCol(
      SQLHSTMT       StatementHandle,
      SQLUSMALLINT   ColumnNumber,
      SQLSMALLINT    TargetType,
      SQLPOINTER     TargetValuePtr,
      SQLLEN         BufferLength,
      SQLLEN *       StrLen_or_Ind);
```

How do I know how much bytes I should allocate?

The only thing I can think of is getting the `SQL_DESC_LENGTH` using `SQLGetDescField`, but I would have to execute the query twice then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out I confused the order in which the functions are run, the correct order is:

1. `SQLBindParameter`
2. `SQLExecDirect`
3. `SQLBindCol`

For `SQLBindParameter` (at least for input parameters) the lengths are already known before the statement is executed.

After `SQLExecDirect` you can use the `SQLNumResultCols` and `SQLGetDescField` functions to determine the number of columns, their data types, lengths, etc.

The SQL92/CLI (call level interface) documentation has an example in appendix `B.2 Interactive Query` that uses `SQLDescribeCol` to get the length.

Answer (score 0):

Call SQLDescribeCol before binding.